# Two awaits with try/catch

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, try-catch

How can i resolve it? If the API call doesn't resolve, it doesn't enter the database call, and it ends up in the catch

```
router.get('/pokemons', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name } = req.query;

        const apiName = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`)

        if (apiName) {
            return res.status(200).json({
                data: apiName.data.abilities
            });
        }

        const dbName = await Pokemon.findAll({
            where: {
                name
            }
        })

        return res.status(200).json({
            data: dbName
        })

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ 
            message: "No existe Pokemon con ese nombre",
            error: err
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Yes, this is how `try/catch` works.  If you want to handle an error in the first `await` differently than the second, you can wrap each `await` in their own try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon` API is either not responding fast or having some issue. if you are not having more control over this API, you can
**Set timeout for API call**. if within that time period API does not respond, do further action.

OR Try Below Code:

```
router.get('/pokemons', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name } = req.query;

        let apiName = "";

        try {
          apiName = await axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${name}`);
        }
        catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }

        if (apiName != "") {
            return res.status(200).json({
                data: apiName.data.abilities
            });
        }

        const dbName = await Pokemon.findAll({
            where: {
                name
            }
        })

        return res.status(200).json({
            data: dbName
        })

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ 
            message: "No existe Pokemon con ese nombre",
            error: err
        })
    }
});
```